# Executar Script em tela aberta por Modal em Ajax. C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, mvc

Problema: Estou na view Index, nela tenha um botão que abre a view Create em uma tela modal, nessa tela modal quero executar um código javascript, mas por algum motivo o mesmo não está sendo executado.

Estou abrindo uma view em modal com o seguinte código:

```
$("#btnNovo").click(function () {
  $(".modal-body").load("/Pais/Create", function () {
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
  });
});
```

View aberta em modal.

```
@model Projeto.WebERP.EntityFramework.Entities.Pais
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = null;
}

<h2> Cadastro de País </h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Handle)

    <hr />
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- DESCRICAO -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="txtDescricao"> Descrição: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, new { type = "text", @class = "form-control", id = "txtDescricao" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <!-- SIGLA -->
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtSigla"> Sigla: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Sigla, new { type = "text", @class = "form-control", id = "txtSigla" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sigla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <!-- DATACADASTRO -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="txtDataCadastro"> Data Cadastro: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataCadastro, new { type = "datetime", @class = "form-control", readOnly = true, id = "txtDataCadastro" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataCadastro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <!-- DATAALTERACAo -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="txtDataAlteracao"> Data Alteração: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataAlteracao, new { type = "datetime", @class = "form-control", readOnly = true, id = "txtDataAlteracao" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataAlteracao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" id="sumitForm" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("dsdsd");
    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Não coloque seu javascript no modal e sim na view original (que abre o modal) e funcionará.

Comment: Então, aí que está, mas se eu coloca e meu JavaScript na view original eu não consigo pegar as tão da view que está no modal! 

Comment: o que seria as "tão" da view?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que analisei do seu código, caso o modal seja carregado pelo ajax, inclua o código js no success do ajax, ele será seu **.ready**

```
$("#btnNovo").click(function () {
  $(".modal-body").load("/Pais/Create", function () {
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    alert("alerta");
  });
});
```